# Remove an object based on some condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Name    {
    public string language { get; set; } 
    public string text { get; set; } 
}

public class ValueItem    {
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public List<Name> names { get; set; } 
    public object syn { get; set; } 
    public List<string> prop { get; set; } 
    public string dataType { get; set; } 
}

public class Source    {
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
}

public class Result    {
    public List<ValueItem> valueItems { get; set; } 
    public Source source { get; set; } 
}

public class Data    {
    public List<Result> result { get; set; } 
    public int totalpages { get; set; } 
    public int totalrecords { get; set; } 
    public int pagesize { get; set; } 
    public int pagenumber { get; set; } 
}
```

i have the model structure like above, i am trying to remove **Name** object based on **text**. If the string which i pass is there in the Name.text, that particular name object should be removed. How to achieve this with linq or lambda.
i have tried : `var data1= data.Result.Where(x=>x.ValueItems.Where(a=>a.Names.SelectMany(b=>!str.Contains(b.Text)))).ToList()`

Comment: Try this (I think it should work): `var data1= data.Result.Where(x=>x.ValueItems.Where(a=>a.Names.Any(b=>b.Text.Contains(str)))).ToList();`. You said if the text contains the string, not viceversa, which is what you are doing. The negation also doesn't match what you say you want as a result.

Comment: Just to make sure: 1) The linq query will not remove any objects, it will return a new list with the filtered results, and 2) If white spaces are irrelevant, you might want to trim the input string before using it in the query.

Comment: If the condition matches should the entire `result` object should be removed or only the `name`? the linq that you are using is filtering the `result` object not the `names`. Can you please provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by returning the filtered version of the original data:

```cs
data.result = data.result.Select(x => new Result
{
    source = x.source,
    valueItems = x.valueItems.Select(a =>
                                         new ValueItem
                                         {
                                             prop = a.prop,
                                             dataType = a.dataType,
                                             id = a.id,
                                             syn = a.syn,
                                             names = a.names
                                                     .Where(i => i.text != stringToRemove)
                                                            .ToList()
                                         }).ToList()

}).ToList();
```

However, an alternative version (without using LINQ) of achieving the same could be:

```cs
foreach (var result in data.result)
{
    foreach (var resultValueItem in result.valueItems)
    {
        resultValueItem.names.RemoveAll(i => i.text == stringToRemove);
    }
}
```

*Note: it's worth to mention that the second option is more effective in terms of performance, because there are no memory allocations happening here.*

---

A few notes for the above solutions:

1. If you don't want the **exact match**, but the scenarios when your text can be part of the bigger string, use [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1), instead of the above comparison.
2. Consider applying one of the: [String.ToLower](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netcore-3.1), [String.ToLowerInvariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=netcore-3.1), [String.ToUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netcore-3.1), [String.ToUperInvariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupperinvariant?view=netcore-3.1), methods to both `stringToRemove` and `i.text` in case if you want case-insensitive comparison.